# Learning For and While Loops and I'm confused about the output of this code

Tags: java

```
int index = 1, balance = 1000;
while (index % 2 == 1)
{
 balance -= index;
 index = index * 2 + 1;
}
System.out.println(balance);
```

I don't understand how the output of this is 1033. How would the code end?
How would the code even end. It seems like the condition will always be fulfilled. Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: What should be the output as per your calculation?

Comment: When `index` overflows and becomes negative, `index%2` won't be 1 any more.

Comment: `balance` can be negative ?

Comment: because Java the max integer value is 2147483647. As you keep doubling the index value the integer value keeps overflowing

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int index = 1, balance = 1000;

    while (index % 2 == 1)
    {
      balance -= index;
      index = index * 2 + 1;
      System.out.println(index);
      System.out.println(String.format("The index value when balance is %d is %d", balance, Integer.MAX_VALUE));
    }
    System.out.println(balance);
  }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Java `index % 2` returns 1 for positive odd numbers, and -1 for negative odd numbers.

If you keep doubling `index`, pretty soon it will overflow, and then it will become negative. At that point `index % 2 == 1` will no longer be true.